# Graphical representation of input parsing in TCL/Tk

Tags: parsing, graphics, tcl, tk-toolkit

I am writing an [RDP parser in Tcl](http://pastebin.com/VnFn1E30). It parses the input successfully and differentiates between the tokens. I want to also print out graphical representations of the input in state transition diagrams [like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEagT.jpg). Any tips or code on how to start about this? I have tried looking into the Canvas function but I cant get my head around how to implement it.

Comment: Are you trying to draw a picture of the parser or of a particular parse tree? Have you looked into graphviz?

Answer (score 0):

SQLite's [syntax diagram generator](https://wiki.tcl.tk/21708) is a mature solution with a simple domain-specific language. It generates PostScript and uses ImageMagick to convert it to GIF.

Alternatives include:

- TkLib's [diagram](http://core.tcl.tk/tklib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tklib/files/modules/diagrams/diagram.html) package. There is little example code for it and the example code in TkLib's [repository](http://core.tcl.tk/tklib/dir?ci=trunk&name=examples/diagrams) is **obsolete**, so you will have to figure out how to use this library on your own.
- [Playing UML](https://wiki.tcl.tk/2257).
- See the [data visualization](https://wiki.tcl.tk/37346) wiki page for others.